# passenger 5.1.11 update, node socket.io error

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, passenger

After updating from passenger 1:5.1.5-1~jessie1 to this new version. We got the following error in the browser:

> Failed to load
>   https://aaa.bbb.com/socket.io/?hash=1735f35ec0ad4e4d91618861288467ed&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LzIr1i8:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://aaa.bbb.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

nginx error log:

> 2017/10/25 11:42:24 [error] 638#638: *20
>   "/export/home/aaa.bbb.com/public/socket.io/index.html" is not found
>   (2: No such file or directory), client: 111.111.111.111, server:
>   aaa.bbb.com, request: "GET
>   /socket.io/?hash=1735f35ec0ad4e4d91618861288467ed&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LzIwLNC
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "aaa.bbb.com", referrer:
>   "https://ccc.bbb.com/mmmm/zzzz/"

As you can see we are using socket.io (1.5.1). Our socket.io server has node.js (v6.11.5) and passenger (5.1.11) installed on it.

We had never before had to set the origin. The web server and the socket server are both on the same domain only different subdomains.

But probably the error in the nginx log is the real issue.

**Edit**

I've updated socket.io on the client and the server side to version 2.0.4. But I run still into the same errors

**Edit 2**

Passenger has crashed when starting. Probably due to permissions issue.

> 2017/10/25 16:15:59 [info] 315#315: Using 32768KiB of shared memory
>   for nchan in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:84 [ N 2017-10-25 16:15:59.9486
>   612/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1267 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
>   [ E 2017-10-25 16:15:59.9993 617/T1 age/Sha/Fun/Initialization.cpp:569
>   ]: *** ERROR: Cannot open /var/log/nginx/error.log for writing:
>   Permission denied (errno=13)
>        in 'Passenger::VariantMap Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::initializeAgent(int, char***, const
>   char*, Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::OptionParserFunc,
>   Passenger::Agent::Fundamentals::PreinitializationFunc, int)'
>   (Initialization.cpp:538)
>
> 2017/10/25 16:15:59 [alert] 609#609: Unable to start the Phusion
>   Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during
>   startup: Unable to start the Passenger core: it seems to have crashed
>   during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown
>   error)

Comment: Please include your nginx config and more logs, especially around Passenger startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the update I set passenger_user_switching to off. This made the passenger process automatically run as nobody:noboby

```
passenger_user_switching off;
```

After the update I set explicitly the passenger_user and passenger_group to run as nobody:noboby (default passenger_user_switching is on)

```
# passenger_user_switching off;
passenger_user nobody;
passenger_group nobody;
```

Comment: This looks like the issue that will be fixed when this branch is landed: https://github.com/phusion/passenger/commit/d41f239d09f6840ede47d0f74a3e3365532d1489